# How to select Data in Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-4, elastic-stack

I'm Using ELK with Kibana 4 and have a problem there:

I'm supervising several systems, which write logs in different frequencies. SystemA gives me a log every hour, SystemB every 12 hours. Every log contains the total number of ItemA at the log point.

now, I want to have a Diagram with the total number of ItemA in all systems combined, on a daly basis. But if I just use Sum of ItemA, it will count SystemA 24 times and SystemB 2 times and therefore get's the sum wrong.

Any Ideas how I can fix that? Thank you

Comment: Can you brief your problem , may be using examples

Comment: a very simplified example is written already. Is it not clear to understand?

Comment: Nope , i fail to understand. Can you provide the raw JSON level example.

Comment: Assuming these are my data:  [{
    "ItemCountA": 100,
    "System": "SystemA",
    "@version": "1",
    "@timestamp": "2015-11-04T12:10:35.000Z"
  },{
    "ItemCountA": 100,
    "System": "SystemA",
    "@version": "1",
    "@timestamp": "2015-11-04T16:10:35.000Z"
  },{
    "ItemCountA": 100,
    "System": "SystemB",
    "@version": "1",
    "@timestamp": "2015-11-04T12:10:35.000Z"
  }
]  So I want to have the sum per day of ItemCountA in all Systems. So 200, not 300

Comment: In kibana you can apply  sql consult... only do of the systemA.  Other option is to set x as System and the y as itemcoount, you will obtain a graph with the information of each System.

Comment: Plotting them on different axis will give me the correct count per system, thats right. but how do I get the sum over time from there?